# Why does this paragraph element prevent jQuery from working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the script below, when I replace the line break tag with a paragraph tag in front of the anchor, the 'shrink' jQuery function doesn't work - the table is always displayed and doesn't shrink when I click the label.

This is true whether or not I apply the closing paragraph tag.

EG: In the example below, panel one (with the line break tag) will toggle, but panel two (with the paragraph tag) will be static.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>tryShrink</title>
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
tryShrink
<br><a href="#" class="Shrink">panel one</a>
<ul>
<li>line1
<li>line2
<li>line3
</ul>

<p><a href="#" class="Shrink">panel two</a>
<ul>
<li>line4
<li>line5
<li>line6
</ul>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.Shrink').click(function() {
        $(this).next().toggle();
        return false;
    }).next().hide();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course, I could always use 2 line breaks instead of a paragraph, but I'd like to understand why an innocuous tag can break jQuery.

Comment: What is expected result? Are you trying to select `<ul>` element?

Comment: **Always** close your `p` tag so the browser doesn't have to guess where your block element, in this case, paragraph, ends. Invalid HTML often leads to unexpected results. Please see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p

Comment: As I mentioned in the original question, closing the paragraph did not fix the problem.

Comment: @JonP: The HTML is actually valid. A `p` element is one that lets you elide the closing tag, though you need to be aware of the rules. It just so happens that of all the elements, the rules for eliding a `</p>` are more complex than other elements by far, so I'd generally agree with your advice in this case. Things like `<li>`, `<td>`, `<tr>` or `<option>` have easy and sensible rules, so sometimes I do drop the closing tag for those.

Comment: @zippydippy in hindsight you are 100% correct! Let me rephrase.... **Always** close your `p` tag so you don't have to guess where the browser will. (Due to those complex rules you've mentioned). For OP, always err on the side of caution and remove ambiguity, even for those tags that are optional to close, that zippy mentioned. Every web dev I've ever worked with closes every tag that isn't a void element, unless they forget to.

Comment: @JonP While I agree wholeheartedly, in this case putting an end tag after the </ul> (as the OP intended) won't fix the problem. The P would still end at the <ul>!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because a `ul` (or any block level element) can not be inside a `p` element, so its presence closes the unclosed `<p>`. Therefore, the `.Shrink` is the only child of `p`, and has no `.next()`.

So the `<p>` isn't as innocuous as you think. It radically changed the structure of the DOM. Understanding the semantics of the various element types is important, as they must be used properly.

Since you want the break to be above the `<a>`, you could simply close the `<p>` properly before the `<a>`, and it'll work, though a `<br>` seems like a better way to add a break.

```
<p></p>
<a href="#" class="Shrink">panel two</a>
<ul>
<li>line4
<li>line5
<li>line6
</ul>
```

Or if you wanted to wrap both the `a` and `ul` elements, use something that is able to nest block elements, like a `div` for example.

```
<div>
    <a href="#" class="Shrink">panel two</a>
    <ul>
    <li>line4
    <li>line5
    <li>line6
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Aha! That must be the problem! But I never heard of the rule "  a ul (or any block level element) can not be inside a p element, ". Where does that come from?

Comment: The rules are given in specifications. The spec that browsers implement is HTML5. It's not the easiest thing to look up information in the spec, so the documentation provided by MDN is usually the way to go. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p It also provides links to the spec(s) toward the bottom of the page.

Comment: Also an option, style the `a` as a block element with the appropriate margin or padding and the meaningless `br` or empty `p` tag can be avoided altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no `next()` now that the Shrink class is inside another parent.

You would need to change to:

```
$('.Shrink').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().toggle();
    return false;
}).parent().next().hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

`<br>` doesn't wrap your first `<a>`, so your next element is the `<ul>`.

```
<br>
<a href="#" class="Shrink">panel one</a>
<ul>
<li>line1
<li>line2
<li>line3
</ul>
```

However, `<p>` wraps your second `<a>` so there's not `next` element:

```
<p>
   <a href="#" class="Shrink">panel two</a>
</p>
<ul>
<li>line4
<li>line5
<li>line6
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  use `.index()` with `this` as parameter to pass to `.eq()` to select next `<ul>` element

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>tryShrink</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      var a = $("a.Shrink");
      var ul =  $("ul").hide();
      a.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ul.eq(a.index(this)).toggle();
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  tryShrink
  <br><a href="#" class="Shrink">panel one</a>
  <ul class="Shrink">
    <li>line1</li>
    <li>line2</li>
    <li>line3</li>
  </ul>

  <p><a href="#" class="Shrink">panel two</a></p>
  <ul class="Shrink">
    <li>line4</li>
    <li>line5</li>
    <li>line6</li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```